# Creating a DSL using nested Elixir macros that can change block context

Tags: ruby, macros, elixir, dsl

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
defmodule ArbitraryContext do
  use Cake

  def make_cake do
    cake do
      name "Chocolate"

      topping do
        name "Butter cream"
        sweetener "Agave"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like `ArbitraryContext.make_cake/0` to produce nested structs along the lines of:

```
%Cake{
  name: "Chocolate",
  topping: %Topping{
    name: "Butter cream",
    sweetener: "Agave"
  }
}
```

I've read Metaprogramming Elixir and quite a few other resources but I can't seem to be able to reproduce some of the DSL flexibility I'm used to in Ruby in Elixir. That seems wrong, as Elixir seems fundamentally more flexible.

I've been following along with the "HTML DSL" example in Metaprogramming Elixir. The HTML example is fundamentally simpler because there is only one module at play - a Tag - so its context can stay the same throughout the nesting. In my case there could be dozens of contexts. I inject Cake macros into the context, which does successfully produce the `%Cake{...}` with a name, but when the block for Topping is unquoted to produce `%Topping{...}`, the context is still `Cake`. No matter what I do, I can't seem to find a clean way to run that block in a new context.

```
defmodule Cake do
  defstruct name: nil

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import Cake
    end
  end

  defmacro cake(do: block) do
    quote do
      # agent-y stuff to maintain state while building the cake. not
      # super important at this time
      {:ok, var!(pid, Cake)} = %Cake{} |> start_state

      # here's where the cake is no longer a lie and the name is set
      unquote(block)

      out = get_state(var!(pid, Cake))
      :ok = stop_state(var!(pid, Cake))
      out
    end
  end

  defmacro topping(block) do
    quote do
      # oh no! block gets evaluated here. even if I double quote
      # block, it still ultimately gets the Cake scope even though I'm
      # passing it into Topping, which is very similar to Cake... meant
      # to build up a Topping struct.
      # 
      # I want to:
      # 1) get block into Topping.topping without unquoting it
      # 2) have the block unquoted in Topping's context, once in there
      Topping.topping(unquote(block))
    end
  end
end
```

In Ruby I'd handle this with something like `Topping.class_eval`... you'd end up with `name` and `sweetener` from `Topping` and on the other side you'd end up with a new Topping class instance.

I can solve this, arguably much cleaner, by just **building** the structs pre-nested without the DSL and all the macros, but I want to understand how to get the intended result using Elixir macros.

I hope I've communicated this question well enough!

Comment: Can you post the source of `Topping`? I think you want `Topping.topping(do: unquote(block))` but since you haven't posted the complete source I can't try it.

Comment: @Dogbert The topping code isn't really all that important or different. The example you provided will unquote the block in Cake's topping macro before ever reaching Topping's macro. But yes, high-level, if the two APIs were the same, you'd want to format the argument as a keyword list with "do".

Comment: Oh. I think you want to call the macro outside quote then, like: `defmacro topping(block) do Topping.topping(block) end`. This will call `Topping.topping/1` with the quoted AST and inject the quoted AST returned by it into the place that called `Cake.topping/1`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to conquer the sea with a railway locomotive. Although it’s still possible to achieve what you want, it’s completely wrong from the perspective of being elixirish, whatever it means.

In the first place, there is no notion of “context.” At all. Everything you have are just plain old good functions. There are two contexts, if you insist on using “context” word: *compilation* and *runtime*.

Elixir macros are more like C/C++ macros, but written in the same language as the main code, which probably confused you. They are being executed during the compilation phase.

**Macros return plain AST, that is to be embedded inplace as is.**

That said, when you declare a macro:

```
defmacro cake(do: block), do: block
```

You end up having a beam (compiled code,) that has all the macros *inlined*. No matter, where they were declared. That’s it. You still might use macros to produce structs, of course, macros are still just plain AST:

```
iex> quote do: %{name: "cake", topping: %{name: "blah"}}
{:%{}, [], [name: "cake", topping: {:%{}, [], [name: "blah"]}]}
```

As soon, as your macro returns quoted representation of your `struct`, e.g. exactly what `quote do` will show for it, it will work. E.g.

```
iex> defmodule A do
...>   defmacro cake(toppling),
...>     do: {:%{}, [], [name: "cake", topping: {:%{}, [], [name: toppling]}]}
...>   def check, do: IO.inspect A.cake("CREAM")
...> end

{:module, A,
 <<70, 79, 82, ...>>, {:check, 0}}

iex> A.check
%{name: "cake", topping: %{name: "CREAM"}}
```

You might use this technique to achieve what you wanted, but it makes not much sense since the whole struct produced cannot be modified in the future. Terms are immutable, remember it.

Hope it clarifies things. Feel free to ask more questions, if you are still curious.

Comment: How would you recommend approaching this instead of macros?

Comment: @Un3qual I would not recommend approaching this at all. If you still feel the necessity to implement the own DSL, the macros is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working thanks to tips from @dogbert and @mudasobwa. As expected, it's gross and messy but it works:

Basic DSL:

```
defmodule ArbitraryContext do
  def make_cake do
    use Cake

    cake do
      name "Chocolate"

      topping do
        name "Butter cream"
        sweetener "Agave"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Cake:

```
defmodule Cake do
  require Topping
  defstruct name: nil, topping: nil

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import Cake
    end
  end

  defmacro cake(do: block) do
    quote do
      {:ok, var!(pid, Cake)} = %Cake{} |> start_state

      unquote(block)

      out = get_state(var!(pid, Cake))
      :ok = stop_state(var!(pid, Cake))
      out
    end
  end

  defmacro topping(do: block) do
    topping = Macro.escape(
      Topping.topping(do: block)
    )

    quote do
      put_state(var!(pid, Cake), :topping, unquote(topping))
    end
  end

  defmacro name(val) do
    quote do
      put_state(var!(pid, Cake), :name, unquote(val))
    end
  end

  def start_state(state), do: Agent.start_link(fn -> state end)
  def stop_state(pid), do: Agent.stop(pid)
  def put_state(pid, key, content), do: Agent.update(pid, fn state -> Map.put(state, key, content) end)
  def get_state(pid), do: Agent.get(pid, &(&1))
end
```

Topping:

```
defmodule Topping do
  defstruct name: nil, sweetener: nil

  def topping(do: block) do
    {:ok, pid} = %Topping{} |> start_state

    Topping.run(pid, block)

    out = get_state(pid)
    :ok = stop_state(pid)
    out
  end

  def run(pid, {_block, _context, ast}) do
    Macro.postwalk(ast, fn segment ->
      run_call(pid, segment)
    end)
  end

  def run(pid, ast), do: ast

  def run_call(pid, {method, _context, args}) do
    apply(Topping, method, [pid] ++ args)
  end

  def run_call(pid, ast), do: ast

  def name(pid, val) do
    put_state(pid, :name, val)
  end

  def sweetener(pid, val) do
    put_state(pid, :sweetener, val)
  end

  def start_state(state), do: Agent.start_link(fn -> state end)
  def stop_state(pid), do: Agent.stop(pid)
  def put_state(pid, key, content), do: Agent.update(pid, fn state -> Map.put(state, key, content) end)
  def get_state(pid), do: Agent.get(pid, &(&1))
end
```

And finally:

```
iex(1)> ArbitraryContext.make_cake
%Cake{name: "Chocolate",
 topping: %Topping{name: "Butter cream", sweetener: "Agave"}}
```

---

As much as I enjoy the DSL, I don't think I'll ultimately use this approach.

A slightly more sensible approach that I also tried is to abandon the Agent business and go straight to parsing the AST statelessly. In the end the complexity was not worth it.